# GET ------ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

[image]Good Evening.... I am getting error for CSS and JS file and showing in console.
Few are as below - Getting this error for 1 page only and for other pages all CSS and JS files are working fine.

While checking the error, i point out the url of 8000/mypagename/....plugin/
is that ok or did i done something wroung. ?

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewBuffalo/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css 
    net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewBuffalo/plugins/datatablesbuttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css 
    net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried to check the file location but they are ok and as mentioned other pages are working fine...
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Rahul Paste your script tag here so I can check how you call it.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css" />
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

Comment: where is your plugins folder?

Comment: Public/plugins
Link are copy paste from other pages which are working fine.....
Thanks for quick reply...

Comment: screenshot added for ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your Your explanation If you have added your css and js inside head tag, you should use asset() provided by laravel like below example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
```

I consider your plugins folder is inside of public folder.

Comment: Will check and revert to you... Thanks

Comment: Just one Point... While reviewing i find one point....May be this will help to get more idea. For working pages url is 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js
and For error page url is - 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewBuffalo/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js.......... Check  plugin folder start after viewBuffalo/ were in working page is start after8000/

Comment: Thanks.... your reply. help me out and solve the problem..... Can u just check my previous comments if possible